# Random tiled background

Tags: css, sass, background-image

I do have 5 tiles with the exact same width/height, I want to know if there is a way to set them as the background randomly.

```
position: relative;
background-image: url(assets/images/bg_tile1.png), url(assets/images/bg_tile2.png), url(assets/images/bg_tile3.png), url(assets/images/bg_tile4.png), url(assets/images/bg_tile5.png);
background-size: auto;
background-repeat: repeat;
```

This is waht i have so far, how could I repeat them randomly? Like if they are in a grid (random):

> 1 4 2 1
>
> 2 3 4 1
>
> 3 1 5 5

Comment: CSS alone can't do random

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can approximate this using SVG. You build a random pattern that will repeat. It won't be completely random but it's a good approximation.

Here is an example with  a 3x3 pattern:

```css
svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="bgimg" x="0" y="0" width="300" height="300"  patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1055/100/100.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="100" width="100" />
      <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1074/100/100.jpg" x="0" y="100" height="100" width="100" />
      <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1080/100/100.jpg" x="0" y="200" height="100" width="100" />
      <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1074/100/100.jpg" x="100" y="0" height="100" width="100" />
      <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1065/100/100.jpg" x="100" y="100" height="100" width="100" />
      <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1039/100/100.jpg" x="100" y="200" height="100" width="100" />
      <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/117/100/100.jpg" x="200" y="0" height="100" width="100" />
      <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1024/100/100.jpg" x="200" y="100" height="100" width="100" />
      <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1025/100/100.jpg" x="200" y="200" height="100" width="100" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="10000" height="10000" fill="url(#bgimg)" />
</svg>
```